# How do I customise MS Word's UI to make commands easier to access?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, macros, context-menu, editing

The question is as stated above in the title. What follows is just background info you can freely skip...

Someone posted an off-topic mini-rant as a comment on one of my answers, bemoaning the loss of the **Select All** command from Word's context menu in recent releases (apparently Open Office still has it). My suggestion of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> wasn't met with enthusiasm since the keyboard combo was apparently easily forgotten, and in any case muscle memory had been built up to simply right-click the document and select the option.

Since that person for some reason wasn't willing to post a question about this issue, I thought I might as well do it on his behalf and provide the solution while I'm at it.

Comment: Ctrl + A easily forgotten? It should be the shortcut used frequently in many other programs and not just Word!

Comment: @Adam: I find it as hard to believe as you do since I use the keyboard extensively, but one must admit not everyone does so, and the guy's age as per his profile indicates that he may be set in his ways... Not trying to be ageist or anything, but I myself find it easier not to confuse aged people by teaching them too many different ways to do the same thing (at least not right at the beginning).

Comment: You have a point there, I often catch both my parents still using the mouse to right click and copy even though they know of the keyboard shortcut. It's slightly frustrating to watch :)

Comment: @Adam: Same here. :) In fact, I often used to take over for them so I could get things done quickly, before I realised that not only is that preventing them from learning, it is also becoming a drain on my time since they started calling on me to do every little thing. Finally I had to step back and tell them that they could ask me for help any time, but they'd have to slowly learn to do things for themselves, no matter how long it took. I'm sure they had a hearty laugh as they remembered teaching me to do stuff back when I was a kid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word 2007 and especially 2010+'s [Fluent User Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29#Microsoft_software) is actually quite customisable. Unfortunately, besides the limited options provided by the program itself any advanced modifications require the use of VBA, XML editing and so on, none of which are a general user's cup of tea. Still, some minor but useful UI modifications can thankfully be achieved without too much trouble or coding. I'm focussing here on the **Select All** command in Word, but this can easily be extended to other commands in other Office apps as well. I've listed a few resources at the end for those who are interested, and of course there's a whole lot more out there if you aren't shy of coding.

### I. Use *Select* button already in ribbon

The first step would be to check if the command is already accessible from the ribbon or elsewhere. If you look on the **Home** tab there's already a **Select** button available and clicking it pops up a menu containing **Select All**:

[image: 1]

### II. Add *Select All* button to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)

1. Right-click the QAT and select **Customize Quick Access Toolbar**
2. Add the command as shown below:

   [image: 2]
3. You should see this in the QAT once you're done:

   [image: 3]

### III. Add *Select All* button to the Ribbon

1. Right-click the ribbon and select **Customize the Ribbon**
2. Add the command as shown below:

   [image: 4]
3. You should see this in the ribbon once you're done:

   [image: 5]

### IV. Add *Select All* option to the context menu

1. On the **View** tab click the **Macros** button and create a new macro (name doesn't really matter since the macro needs to be run just once and then can be deleted):

   [image: 6]
2. Enter the code shown below and click the **Run Macro** button on the toolbar or press <kbd>F5</kbd>:

   ```
   CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
   CommandBars("Text").Controls.Add ID:=756, Before:=1
   ```

   [image: 7]
3. You should see this in the context menu once you're done:

   [image: 8]
4. If you want the option to be added to the bottom of the menu, use the following macro code instead:

   ```
   CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
   CommandBars("Text").Controls.Add ID:=756
   ```

   [image: 9]
5. To delete the newly added option from the top of the menu, use the following code:

   ```
   CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
   CommandBars("Text").Controls.Item(1).Delete
   ```
6. To delete the newly added option from the bottom of the menu, use the following code:

   ```
   CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
   CommandBars("Text").Controls.Item(CommandBars("Text").Controls.Count).Delete
   ```

**Note:** You can delete the macros after running them once. Also, since they affect the **Normal** template you may be prompted to save changes when you exit Word depending on your `File / Options / Advanced / Save` settings:

[image: 10]

Just click **Save** and henceforth **Select All** will show up in all documents based on the **Normal** template:

[image: 11]

**Tip:** If you ever badly mess up your **Normal** template you can simply delete `%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm`. Word will recreate the template with default options next time you run it.

**Resources to help understand/extend macro code:**

- [Working with Command Bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189727.aspx)
- [Application.CustomizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822548.aspx), [Application.CommandBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845623.aspx)
- [Macro that lists all available Word CommandBar Controls and their IDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243988)